# PHP user connection database across differents pages

Tags: php, database, security, authentication, intranet

I'am currently developping an Intranet database interface. My boss wants to track who did which request. This mean no PHP user to acces database. Then I need to ask user's login and password to establish connection.
But a popup with user's login and password input on every pages is undesirable. I thought about php sessions but the password is stored in plain_text on the server which is alors undesirable.
Maybe someone have an idea ?

Comment: You will have to store it _somewhere_, and even if you store it somehow encrypted, you will have to decrypt it at some point … What _exactly_ is the attack scenario you are worried about here?

Comment: @CBroe If someone have acces to the server's files he might be able to retrieve all currently stored passwords. And if i can decrypt the password somebody else will be able to do so with encrypted password.

Comment: Sure, but what alternatives did you expect to exist? If your script needs the username and password for the database connection - then it will have to get access to those, at some point. And anyone with actual server access would probably find a way to log those when the user originally sends them already, totally unrelated to any longer, cross-request storage in the session or elsewhere.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot, I think I'll go with your solution